# Formula not returning match

Tags: google-query-language

I have two files 
File one has a sheet1 called `Form Responses`
File two has a sheet1 called Data

I am trying to match on Col4 of `Form Responses` to Col2 of `Data` and post back Col1 and Col2 of `Form Responses` where there is a match, to the row of the match in `Data`

I have the formula which I am placing in `Data`

But I get no matches and there are matches to be gotten

Thanks

```
=iferror(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1Ew1j6R-Symxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","Form Responses 1!A:Q"), "select Col1,Col2 where Col4="&$B2:B,-1),"")
```

Answer (score 4):

1. First - Query allows to use either columns identifiers (A,B, etc) or columns numbers (Col1, Col2, etc.) - not both at the same time.
2. Second - you can't just compare ranges like that - your defined range is from `"Form Responses"` sheet, so data from `"Data"` sheet are outside given range - so they are not accessible from your query.

What you need is pulling data from `Data$B2:B` into string and then compare with Col4. Probably the easiest way would be using inbuild REGEXMATCH (matches) query. Try:

```
iferror(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1Ew1j6R-Symxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","Form Responses 1!A:Q"),"select Col1,Col2 where Col4 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|",1,$B2:B)&"'",-1),"")
```

I hope it will work for you

Comment: Hello and thanks, but is there a way to get output to be on the row of the match?

Comment: @Einarr - could you be a litter more elaborate? I don’t get what you would like to archive.

Comment: Right now the matches are outputted staring on row2, row3, row4...rowx but I need the output to be on the row of the match so output should be like row 7. row 15...row 112

Comment: Could you provide sample sheets with some data you are working on?